# Cannot exit a blank databound textbox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I am building an Entity Framework database application (C#, SQL Server). I am using textbox fields for several dates that are optional (DataTime?- nullable).  I have Validating Handlers that reject entries that can not be parsed as dates (DateTime.TryParse) but will accept blank entries.  The problem is that if an entry is left blank the textbox field will not allow focus to move away.  This happens even though the Validating Handler has approved it (e.cancel = false).  The Validated Event does not fire.  I cannot find where this backstage invalidation is coming from.

I can’t use the DateTimePicker control because it, of course, cannot be blank either- nor can it be formatted to match the font and colors of the rest of the form.

Additional info-  The user can pass through these fields (TAB) without being  stopped as long as they don't 'touch' them.  Both the the Validating and Validated events fire in this scenario.  However if any text is entered into the field (and then deleted) the user cannot exit the field without entering a valid date.  The Validating event fires but not the Validated event.  No exception is thrown, nor any other feedback given, the user is just stuck.

Additional info- I have found the “AutoValidate” property on the form and tried setting it to EnableAllowFocusChange; this allows the user to exit a blank field, but it also allows them to exit with an invalid date entry as well.  It is also global to the entire form which makes it an unacceptable (non)solution.

Where is this hidden overriding invalidation coming from and how can I intercept/cancel/defeat it?

My Validation Code has been requested:

```
    private void txb_ReleaseDate_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!EditMode["EmployeeRecord"]) return;              // NOT editing EmployeeRecord

        TextBox dataField = (TextBox)sender;
        Boolean isValid = true;

        DateTime testValue;


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataField.Text))                   //  null is acceptable
        {
            isValid = DateTime.TryParse(dataField.Text, out testValue);

            if (!isValid)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid Date for Release, or leave BLANK.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                e.Cancel = true;        
            }

        }

    }

    private void txb_ReleaseDate_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Validated Handler (Release Date) fired");

    }
```

As I mentioned, this code is executing as intended.  The "Validated" code is just for trace purposes, I don't need to take any action there.

Something is de-validating the entry *after* the validating code has run and approved it.

Comment: Sorry but your question is based on false assumptions. `DateTimePicker` can be optional when bound to a `DateTime?` property. Also you need to show some actual code that explains, how your validation workflow is implemented.

Comment: @grek40 Thank you for responding.  I have added my validation code above.
As for the DateTimePicker- it is well documented that it cannot be null.  There are many workarounds posted and people have posted derived controls that add this ability. I have used one of these, and created my own, where a DataTimePicker was acceptable.
As I mentioned in my post the inability to change the color and shape of the DateTimePicker, along with its other formatting limitations make it unsuitable for my immediate needs.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was talking about the `DatePicker` control from standard WPF. What kind of `DateTimePicker` are you talking about?